# Android Google Plus SDK: is PlusClient required to make a +1?

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services, google-plus-one

I included a +1 button in my app. I simply :

1. made the steps 1 to 3 (Enable the Google+ API, Configure your Eclipse project and Declare permissions) mentioned on this page : https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started (I didn't do step 4 "Initialize the PlusClient")
2. I DID NOT do any of the steps mentioned on the sign-in page: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in
3. added the code relative to the +1 button mentioned on this page: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/recommend

It seems that it works on my phone but I wondered if it is a really convenient way to implement the +1 button. Do I miss something?

By the way, what is the minimum required Android SDK version to use the PlusOneButton ? I understand that it is Froyo. How can I add a condition in my xml to guarantee that the PlusOneButton in the xml will be ignored below Froyo?

Comment: The Google Play Service automatically detects which versions of devices will be able to download your app. So, people with older devices will not see your app.